# ListView below ListView (with many items)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I want to have a activity which contains two fragments, one with a listview (much more items than the screen-height can hold) and one with another listview (just a few elements). Fragment A should be above fragment B, but fragment B should only be visible, if the listview in fragment A is scrolled to the end.
An example: ListView1 (fragment A) contains 20 items (screen can hold 6 items at once) and ListView2 contains 3 items

```
Initial view            Scrolled down to end of ListView1

|----------------|      |-----------------|
| ListView1Item1 |      | ListView1Item19 |
| ListView1Item2 |      | ListView1Item20 |
| ListView1Item3 |      |                 |
| ListView1Item4 |      | ListView2Item1  |
| ListView1Item5 |      | ListView2Item2  |
| ListView1Item6 |      | ListView2Item3  |
|----------------|      |-----------------|


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:id="@+id/containerOverview"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/containerKommentar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/containerOverview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I thought I can do it with a ScrollView, but this can only hold one element.

And there is something to notice: Both of my fragments get created programmatically because I need to pass some (dynamic) parameters to it.

I hope you can understand my problem and there is a way to handle it.
Thank you

Comment: `but fragment B should only be visible, if the listview in fragment A is scrolled to the end.` not possible, unless you put the fragment in a view in the footer of the fragment A, but then, a listview would not be appropriate here. I would recommend to try to put all elements in the same ListView, possibly using a MergeAdapter (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)

Comment: You can use item types getItemView() and getItemViewTypeCount() from the adapter class to achieve what you want with a single list and a single adapter.

Answer (score 0):

you set first listView height to `wrap_content`, if item is too long so it will take full of screen, you can do two thing:

1) use LinearLayout and set weight for each listView , second listView visibility should be gone  and you set onScrollListener for your first ListView and check if `firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= allItem` then your list is in end now you can change visibility of second listView to true.

2) do not use linearLayout and do other thing same as (1) but also change height of first listView dynamically.